# Oracle apex , Query problem in date field

Tags: oracle-apex, datetimepicker

I have a field of type date in a table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VPAD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq9hR.png)

apex settings of the field as above. It won't let me change the format. this is the default format. When I query from Sql Workshop, I get the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6oTF.png)
how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try out the below code

```
extract(hour from cast(sysdate as timestamp))
```

In the above code replace sysdate with your page items